# Installing consumer software on a server

Tags: best-practices

I am in need of a simple low-maintenance off-site backup solution for one or more Windows servers. I have had great success using some [consumer-grade backup software](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/) that allows me to backup files from one PC to another through the Internet. I've installed this on my own personal computers, as well as several other computers in our office. It has several nice features that make it reliable, easy to maintain, and cost-effective.

I don't know why, but it just feels *dirty* to install consumer-grade software on my servers. Are there any legitimate reasons to avoid consumer-grade software, or is my feeling justified?

These servers don't handle sensitive data other than source code. These are not public Internet servers either; they are only accessed by a team of software developers on a VPN.

Side note: I'm aware of other easy off-site backup solutions meant specifically for servers. For one reason or another, I can't use most of them. That's besides the point though; **this question is not as much about backup software as best practices.**

Comment: You know Crashplan has a "Pro" version as well, right?

Comment: Stop thinking about it as backup software. Think about it instead as _restore_ software, and in that context, evaluate whether it meets your needs.

Comment: @EEAA Yes, their business version requires you to back up to the cloud though. One of my requirements (boss's orders) is to back up to our own hardware. Only the consumer or enterprise version does that, and we're too small for the enterprise version.

Comment: That's an odd requirement, being that you can provide your own encryption key(s), in which case you have no hardware to manage. Sadly, Backup Exec may be your best bet here.

Comment: You say that you need an off-site backup but yet you can't back up to the cloud. Is it your intention to backup to your own off-site hardware? If so, how do you plan to implement and manage that?

Comment: @joeqwerty I do have off-site hardware in a data center that I have physical access to. However that's a discussion I'd rather not start here. I'd be happy to [chat elsewhere](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room#) though.

Comment: Crashplan Pro for the win